# Visual Studio 2013 Express crashes when adding a new file

Tags: visual-studio-2013

VS 2013 Express is crashing when adding any new type of file to a project.

e.g. Trying to add a main.cpp to a new empty C++ project results in the program either hanging then crashing or instantly quitting.

I've tried rebooting, repairing the installation, running in safe mode, re-installing etc. 
The problem continues to persist.

I'm on a Windows 8.1

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Installed Visual Studio Express 2012 and the problem is occurring there too. It is not occurring in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with /resetsettings or /safemode?  If you are moving back and forth between versions, you could have settings from one version effecting the other.